# Unable to rotate kml layer

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, kml

I want to rotate the kml layer in my map but it is not rotating however kml file contains the rotation tag. Here is KML file.

[KML File](https://s3.amazonaws.com/navizon.its.fp/1001/zk01w7hhv4_o.kml)

I am using this code to include the kml file.

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    center: myLatLng
});

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/navizon.its.fp/1001/zk01w7hhv4_o.kml',
    map: map
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`<rotation/>` is not supported in KmlLayer, see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps for supported elements

Comment: Here is sample from google. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml It contains rotation tag.

Comment: *The KML parser generally silently ignores XML tags it does not understand* ....the Maps-API didn't support(understand) `<rotation/>`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be the third party KML parser [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) which now supports the `<GroundOverlay>` `<rotation>` tag (with a change to the helper ProjectedOverlay library). (Disclaimer: I am currently the maintainer).

[example with your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/3d-islands_comaisbucket_20163.kml)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 0
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

  var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    infoWindow: infowindow,
    singleInfoWindow: true,
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlData);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

var kmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><Document><name>course_3.kml</name><Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin"><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color><width>3</width></LineStyle></Style><Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin"><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color><width>2.5</width></LineStyle></Style><StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin"><Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl></Pair><Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl></Pair></StyleMap><Folder><name>Bucket Regatta 2014 - Around the Island Cours (Short)</name><open>1</open><Placemark><name>Bucket Regatta 2014 - Around the Island Cours (Short)</name><styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl><LineString><tessellate>1</tessellate><coordinates>-62.86033284828354,17.8845504927191,0 -62.84458650469701,17.87473959704673,0 -62.83547659050955,17.86945167794833,0 -62.83388304026133,17.86867910723514,0 -62.83321075835203,17.86842764302893,0 -62.83244614152226,17.86829326710066,0 -62.83095108255348,17.86812958593426,0 -62.8252089501432,17.86760084008422,0 -62.81367914534573,17.86719796434468,0 -62.8028525753019,17.86714467828739,0 -62.79756667270858,17.86751051155173,0 -62.79509376490336,17.86786570346247,0 -62.79412412763578,17.86809155768074,0 -62.79338147339845,17.86834753898355,0 -62.79292197702473,17.86872845424952,0 -62.79236941605821,17.86972789718922,0 -62.79196728876664,17.87057855391474,0 -62.79095434506525,17.87302053688485,0 -62.78769902736699,17.88296771449728,0 -62.78520601621152,17.8921161942094,0 -62.78298714148205,17.90141446335292,0 -62.78215426430953,17.90588128332446,0 -62.78180288654804,17.9081463412259,0 -62.78171537826803,17.90959573053742,0 -62.78176111029458,17.91085157814362,0 -62.78209906045792,17.91195531708489,0 -62.78278820483929,17.91396330057004,0 -62.78453903421586,17.91810287947595,0 -62.78752730575776,17.92390658974894,0 -62.78875333123023,17.9259212696348,0 -62.78986544653639,17.92755568861479,0 -62.79078421150102,17.92859792870751,0 -62.79831145019485,17.93443063643228,0 -62.80584033616613,17.94020945772508,0 -62.81258307095833,17.94514006132481,0 -62.81448933178827,17.94638884742845,0 -62.81601070417865,17.94716110662928,0 -62.81775976509371,17.94767575361211,0 -62.81986862853103,17.94779702318609,0 -62.82149546368095,17.94779229499462,0 -62.82371517654716,17.94766157324279,0 -62.82621465923376,17.94746630950224,0 -62.83049328518798,17.94705904912,0 -62.83919972063341,17.9459216448811,0 -62.84628848778544,17.94477832659337,0 -62.85888853921235,17.94250489675832,0 -62.87239257119431,17.93981825881495,0 -62.8811980398479,17.9377795947891,0 -62.88775645578315,17.93609294178501,0 -62.89173988675277,17.93489414228672,0 -62.89412558290244,17.93395197835972,0 -62.89552567301983,17.93307595570021,0 -62.89648507743102,17.93172350534812,0 -62.89669004691491,17.93099109405102,0 -62.89675976559775,17.93021394953048,0 -62.89663735225985,17.92926394813965,0 -62.89634128071585,17.92835412072944,0 -62.89557221863525,17.9270680837545,0 -62.89388090053903,17.92485240345483,0 -62.87826523882355,17.9063455885609,0 -62.86096890036382,17.88703596862992,0 </coordinates></LineString></Placemark><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.88892896821306</north><south>17.88720675592857</south><east>-62.86037690770465</east><west>-62.86354378113808</west><rotation>307.820971098897</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.88462189853965</north><south>17.88289968625519</south><east>-62.85754360921412</east><west>-62.86071048264756</west><rotation>323.6259195552798</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.86797860237289</north><south>17.86625639008843</south><east>-62.80737139571207</east><west>-62.8105382691455</west><rotation>357.5851829764764</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.90390563534902</north><south>17.90218342306457</south><east>-62.78104451432495</east><west>-62.78421138775838</west><rotation>77.74273626527004</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.94462710084591</north><south>17.94290488856144</south><east>-62.80891396332905</east><west>-62.81208083676248</west><rotation>142.8275337342407</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.94188422571256</north><south>17.94016201342811</south><east>-62.86522147937472</east><west>-62.86838835280815</west><rotation>191.2539027987112</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay><GroundOverlay><name>Untitled Image Overlay</name><open>1</open><Icon><href>http://3d-islands.com/ais/bucket_2013/trace_day3.png</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>17.92371079228007</north><south>17.92198857999562</south><east>-62.89070522661952</east><west>-62.89387210005297</west><rotation>307.3348255545322</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></Folder></Document></kml>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/kmz/ZipFile.complete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/kmz/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```