# How to rotate a KML Layer containing a GroundOverlay in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

I have loaded a historic map image into Google Earth Pro and adjusted its position, stretched and rotated it until it aligns with the ground reasonably well.

From Google Earth I saved this as a KML and uploaded it so both the KML and the [image](https://storage.googleapis.com/historic_map_overlays/MMBW_1264.kml) are publicly available

The [KML file](https://storage.googleapis.com/historic_map_overlays/MMBW_1264.kml) is copied below. It includes a rotation, and the color includes an alpha component.

However, the image is not rotated and the alpha is ignored - so the image is opaque.

I tried loading the image directly as a GroundOverlay, but this has no rotation option in google maps api v3.

My question is how do I overlay the image on the map with a rotation and how can I make it partially transparent?

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -37.83433865, lng:  144.96147273999998 }
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/historic_map_overlays/MMBW_1264.kml',
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<GroundOverlay>
    <name>MMBW_1264</name>
    <color>ccffff80</color>
    <Icon>
        <href>https://storage.googleapis.com/historic_map_overlays/DetailPlan_1264_alpha.jpg</href>
        <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
        <north>-37.784899</north>
        <south>-37.788269</south>
        <east>144.996226</east>
        <west>144.989129</west>
        <rotation>27.57004115033846</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question: [Unable to rotate kml layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003309/unable-to-rotate-kml-layer)

`<rotation/>` is not supported in [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml), see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements for supported elements

One option would be the third party KML parser [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) which supports the `<GroundOverlay>` `<rotation>` tag. (Disclaimer: I am currently the maintainer).

[example with your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/GroundOverlayRotation.kml)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 0
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

  var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    infoWindow: infowindow,
    singleInfoWindow: true,
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlData);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

var kmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><GroundOverlay><name>MMBW_1264</name><color>ccffff80</color><Icon>        <href>https://storage.googleapis.com/historic_map_overlays/DetailPlan_1264_alpha.jpg</href><viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox><north>-37.784899</north>   <south>-37.788269</south><east>144.996226</east><west>144.989129</west> <rotation>27.57004115033846</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/kmz/ZipFile.complete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/kmz/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer indicated, Google Maps supports most but not all of the KML spec, and the `<rotation>` tag unfortunately is one of the things that is not supported. Details on what KML is supported in Maps is in the documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer

Another option might be to bring your map image into a GIS package like QGIS, georeference and rotate it there, and then export a larger image that's N/S/E/W aligned (un-rotated), and includes transparent padding to account for the rotation. That way  you could add it to your map via KML and not require rotation.  Also, that way, you can add transparency directly into the image file.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the docs Christiaan. That spells out what is not supported. Although it would be good if it was supported ;-)  The geoXml library seems to work in my case. The approach you describe would also work. With a lot of images to overlay it is not clear which approach would have the best workflow. Using QGIS and image tools I could also extract the ink lines as an alpha channel and make the background transparent - so there are some benefits.